# asp.net regular expression doesn't check correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression

I have a simple regularExpression which checks to see if the given information is only 4 digits long and only contains digits. I have something that works but it doesn't allow the user to start the first digit off as a 0, any ideas why? Here is my regularexpression

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{4,4}$", ErrorMessage = "PIN did not follow the correct format of 4-digits")]
```

More information

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please input your 4 digit pin.")]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{4,4}$", ErrorMessage = "PIN did not follow the correct format of 4-digits")]
        [Display(Name = "PIN")]
        public long PIN { get; set; }

Comment: Do you have any other validation on the input?

Comment: Just to be sure: this attribute is applied on a `string` type right?

Comment: it is applied on a long, no more validation is done

Comment: Ah, there's the problem. When you format a long to a string it removes the leading zero's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) the regular expression is fine with numbers starting with zero. It looks like the problem is related to another issue.

A `long` cannot start with zero - PIN should be of type `string`.